# Parse CDATA with R

Tags: r, xml, web-scraping, rvest

I'm scraping and analyzing data from a car auction website. My goal is to develop date-time and sentiment analysis skills, and I like old cars. The website is Bring A Trailer-- they do not offer API access (I asked), but robots.txt is OK.

SO user '42' pointed out that this is not permitted by BAT's terms, so I have removed their base url. I will likely remove the question. After thinking about it, I can do what I want by saving a couple of webpages from my browser and analyzing that data. I don't need ALL the auctions, I just followed a tutorial that did and here I am reading TOS instead of doing what I wanted in the first place...

Some of the data is easily accessed, but the best parts are hard, and I'm stuck with that. I'm really looking for advice on my approach.

My first steps work: I can find and locally cache the webpages:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

data_dir <- "bat_data-html/"

# Step 1: Create list of links to listings ----------------------------
base_url <- "https://"
pages <- read_html(file.path(base_url,"/auctions/")) %>%
  html_nodes(".auctions-item-title a") %>%
  html_attr("href") %>%
  file.path

pages <- head(pages, 3) # use a subset for testing code

# Step 2 : Save auction pages locally ---------------------------------
dir.create(data_dir, showWarnings = FALSE)
p <- progress_estimated(length(pages))

# Download each auction page
walk(pages, function(url){
  download.file(url, destfile = file.path(data_dir, basename(url)), quiet = TRUE)
  p$tick()$print()
})
```

I can also process metadata about the auction from these cached pages, identifying the css selectors with SelectorGadget and specifying them to rvest:

```
# Step 3: Process each auction info into df ----------------------------
files <- dir(data_dir, pattern = "*", full.names = TRUE)

# Function: get_auction_details, to be applied to each auction page
get_auction_details <- function(file) {
  pagename <- basename(file) # the filename of the page (trailing index for multiples)
  page <- read_html(file)   # read the html into R ( consider , options = "NOCDATA")
  # Grab the title of the auction stored in the ".listing-post-title" tag on the page
  title <- page %>% html_nodes(".listing-post-title") %>% html_text()
  # Grab the "BAT essentials" of the auction stored in the ".listing-essentials-item" tag on the page
  essence <- page %>% html_nodes(".listing-essentials-item") %>% html_text()
  # Assemble into a data frame
  info_tbl0 <- as_tibble(essence)
  info_tbl <- add_row(info_tbl0, value = title, .before = 1)
  names(info_tbl) [1] <- pagename
  return(info_tbl)
} 

# Apply the get_auction_details function to each element of files

bat0 <- map_df(files, get_auction_details)         # run function
bat <- gather(bat0) %>% subset(value != "NA")      # serialize results

# Save as csv
write_csv(bat, path = "data-csv/bat04.csv") # this table contains the expected metadata:

key,value
1931-ford-model-a-12,Modified 1931 Ford Model A Pickup
1931-ford-model-a-12,Lot #8576
1931-ford-model-a-12,Seller: TargaEng
```

But the auction data (bids, comments) is inside of a CDATA section:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var BAT_VMS = { ...bids, comments, results  
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

I've tried elements within this section using the path that I find using SelectorGadget, but they are not found-- this gives an empty list:

```
tmp <- page %>% html_nodes(".comments-list") %>% html_text()
```

Looking at the text within this CDATA section, I see some xml tags but it is not structured in the cached file like it is when I inspect the auction section of the live webpage.

To extract this information, should I try to parse the information "as-is" from within this CDATA section, or can I transform it so that it can be parsed like XML? Or am I barking up the wrong tree?

I appreciate any advice!

Comment: I think you need to also determine what the terms of service say about automated downloading of content. The robots.txt is really only a sign that they allow spiders/crawlers to index the site. The "Terms" page says no scraping.

Comment: Well that's disappointing, I guess I need to find another auction site.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I suppose I should take the question down.

Answer (score 0):

It's buried in the XML2 documentation, but you can use this option to keep the CDATA intact.

```
# Instead of rvest::read_html()
xml2::read_xml(options = "NOCDATA")
```

After reading the feed in this way, you'll be able to access the comments list the way you wanted.

```
tmp <- page %>% html_nodes(".comments-list") %>% html_text()
```